# Como pegar apenas o mês de uma data com Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, data, laravel-5.3

Preciso pegar apenas o mês de uma data que vem por um `$request`. Porém não sei como fazer:

```
if ($request->parcelas > 1) {
        $mes = $request->data_vencimento = date('m');
        for($i = 0; $i <= $request->parcelas; $i++) {
            if($request->data_vencimento = date('m') == 12 ){
                $mes = 1;
            }
            var_dump($request->data_vencimento = date('Y-'. $mes . '-d'));
            $mes ++;
        }
    }
```

A data vem no formato `dd/mm/yyyy`

Dessa forma ele pega da data atual. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Em que formato ela vem?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método `DateTime::createFromFormat`  para instanciar um objeto `DateTime` a partir da data no formato desejado.

Veja:

```
$vencimento = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->data_vencimento);

dd($vencimento->format('m'));
```

Ou seja, no seu caso, poderia ficar assim:

```
if ($request->parcelas > 1) {

    $vencimento = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->data_vencimento);

    $mes = $vencimento->format('m');

    // resto do código
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver enviando a data no formato `yyyy-mm-dd` você pode pegar assim: `date('m', strtotime($request->data_vencimento))`.

Comment: Ela vem em formato dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Assim também você retorna apenas o mês

```
date( 'm' , strtotime($request->data_vencimento));
```